# What is the max HP of a level 5 ranger with a Constitution modifier of +2?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, hit-points

What’s a level 5 ranger's max hit points with a Constitution modifier of +2?

Is it hit die plus modifier?
So (10+2)*5

Lvl 1 = 12
Lvl 2 = 24
Lvl 3 = 36
Lvl 4 = 48
Lvl 5 = 60

Seems high.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Have you read the 5e basic rules, specifically regarding how hit points are affected as they go up in levels?

Comment: Related: [How do you calculate your character's Maximum Hit Points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62432/how-do-you-calculate-your-characters-maximum-hit-points), [Is Con modifier × level added to HP every level-up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48156/is-con-modifier-%c3%97-level-added-to-hp-every-level-up), [Do the rules specify that you add your CON bonus to HP when taking the average at leveling up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101763/do-the-rules-specify-that-you-add-your-con-bonus-to-hp-when-taking-the-average-a)

Comment: Are you asking for a literal maximum (including other features), or just the maximum from the rolled dice and Constitution modifier?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you calculate your character's Maximum Hit Points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62432/how-do-you-calculate-your-characters-maximum-hit-points)

Answer (score 7):

From the PHB (p. 90):

> Hit Points at 1st Level: 10 + your Constitution modifier
>
> Hit Points at Higher Levels: 1d10 (or 6) + your Constitution modifier per ranger level after 1st

So yes, based on just your hitdie rolls, the *absolute maximum* at level 5 would be 60, as you calculated. However the *chance* of that happening is pretty astronomical (.01% chance of getting a 10 on 4 consecutive d10 rolls). That's why it would appear to be a "bit high".

That said, there are feats and race/class features that can boost this further, like the Hill Dwarf's [Dwarven Toughness](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Hill%20Dwarf#h-Hill%20Dwarf) feature, or the [Tough](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/tough) feat (PHB, p. 170).

Comment: @MikeQ: The total increase per level is between 3 and 12 HP because it's 1d10 plus a Con mod of 2.

Comment: @MikeQ I don't think the question actually wants the literal maximum, but is just asking about the base HP from class levels

Comment: @MikeQ: There are also other race/class features that could increase one's max HP (e.g. Dwarven Toughness, Draconic Resilience).

Comment: Clarified the max based on hit die rolls

Comment: You get 10 hp at first level so you only need to roll 4 sequential 10s for a much more reasonable 0.01% chance.